# Big Sur Mac Mail: display date and time received?

Tags: mail.app, big-sur

Is there a way to force Mail in Big Sur to display the Date Received column as a date *and time*, not a mere date? Times are important. If there's a way to make Mail do this, what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selecting Mail > View > Show Date and Time will display date and time in 'Date received' column except today (displays only time) and yesterday (instead of date it uses 'Yesterday')

Comment: Is there any way to get it to show the actual date, instead of "yesterday"?